# Why is row counting in MVC not working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my view I have this table, in which the first column is a sequential number (Event column):

```
<table class="tabela">
    <tr class="titles">
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Variable 1</th>
        <th>Variable 2</th>
    </tr>
    @if (Model.Variables != null)
    {
        const int event = 0;
        foreach (var row in Model.Variables)
        {
            <tr align="center">
                <td>@event.ToString()</td>

                <td>@row.Variable1.First()</td>
                <td>@row.Variable2.First()</td>

                @event++;
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

The code above does this (Dogodek is in my language Event):
[image]

I have done some corrections, I have removed const and in foreach put @(event++)

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Remove the `;`. That is incorrect syntax for `Razor`.

Comment: You are trying to increment constant value.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi if I remove ";" result is same, just without ";" in zeros.

Comment: @Konstantin Smolyakov yes I increment constant value, because ReSharper sugested me, do you think that I should use "var" or "int"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be trying like this. It will work

```
@(event++)
```

### Edit 1

```
<tr align="center">
            <td>@event.ToString()</td>
            <td>@row.Variable1.First()</td>
            <td>@row.Variable2.First()</td>
            <td>@(event++)</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: It underline "event" with this error: "Readonly local constant cannot be used as an assignment target"

Comment: because you have declare it as `const int event = 0;` remove `const`.

Comment: ok, I now remove "const" form declaration and leave just int" and it works, but still put numbers out from table, I have post image in my question

Comment: because you design is wrong. you should put it into a `<td>` see my update. Or change your desing

Comment: I apologise, I thing that I remove your update, because I have put image, can you update it again, sorry for my mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have correct my code with help of @Șhȇkhaṝ and code look like this:

```
<table class="tabela">
    <tr class="titles">
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Variable 1</th>
        <th>Variable 2</th>
    </tr>
    @if (Model.Variables != null)
    {
        int event = 1; //if you whant to start from 1 to etc...
        foreach (var row in Model.Variables)
        {
            <tr align="center">
                <td>@(event++)</td>

                <td>@row.Variable1.First()</td>
                <td>@row.Variable2.First()</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

And something else, If you whant to count backward you can do this:

```
<table class="tabela">
    <tr class="titles">
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Variable 1</th>
        <th>Variable 2</th>
    </tr>
    @if (Model.Variables != null)
    {
        int event = Model.Variables.Count; 
        foreach (var row in Model.Variables)
        {
            <tr align="center">
                <td>@(event--)</td>

                <td>@row.Variable1.First()</td>
                <td>@row.Variable2.First()</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Comment: You should mark this as your answer so others can find it later.